# Changing my keyboard settings from unknown back to german on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, keyboard, german

I have my keyboard settings unwillingly changed
System ubuntu 14.04 lts
all my german letters are giving other symbols. The Z and the Y have changed position and all the shift symbols above the numbers are changed. The @ is now shift 2

Can someone give me the information to come back to an german keybord. 
I am just an user so please give only keyboard commands

Answer (score 0):

In most cases it is easy to reset the keyboard.

```
setxkbmap de
```

in a terminal window will do it for you.

This kind of setting will not survive a reboot, but probably the action that caused the change of keyboard was also only temporary.

-o-

Afterwards, you can reboot the computer and check what keyboard you get.

If not correct after reboot you should click the icon with a cog wheel and a wrench, and look into the settings for language and keyboard.

Please try to remember, what programs you were running when or just before this happened - running some application programs or maybe installing or updating some program package (updating can be automatic, but *should not* change the keyboard).

-o-

Maybe the keyboard was changed to English (US English is the default). It matches the description, but also some other languages could match that description.